# Handling errors if no network is available

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, axios

I just implemented my first backend file where I fetch some user data, messages and so on.
Now I wanted to include error handling if there is no network available.

I don´t know if I did it right but this was my approach so far:

```
import axios from 'axios'

const host = process.env.VUE_APP_URL

export default {
  
    
    person: async function (currentPerson) {
        let params = {
            currentPerson: localStorage.getItem("person"),
        };
        if (user) {
            params['currentPerson'] = currentPerson;
        }
        return axios.get(`${host}/api/currentPerson`, {
            params: params
        })
         //catching network errors
         .catch (error => {
            if (error.response) {
                /*
                 * The request was made and the server responded with a 
                 4xx/5xx error
                 */
                console.log(error.response.data);
                console.log(error.response.status);
                console.log(error.response.headers);
            } else if (error.request) {
                /*
                 * The request was made but no response was received
                 */
                console.log(error.request);
            } else {
                // Something happened in setting up the request and triggered an Error
                console.log('Error', error.message);
            }
            console.log(error)
        });
    },
```

In my **mounted()** function of my main view I fetch the data from my backend file from above:

```
backend.matches().then(function (response) {
self.contacts = response.data.persons;
 });
```

I tried to check in console if it is working but all I get is the following:

[image]

In the **catch** block I check for

- **response** errors: like 4xx/5xx
- **request** errors: if my network not responding in time
- and any other errors

Would this be the right approach to check if a network is available or not? Or does it degrade the user experience when the user checks the error?

My backend file includes more methods.. do I have to write for each method these kind of requests?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your backend file you don't react whether there is a network connection or not I think.

And only for reference: that is not the backend, but communicates with the ***backend*** - the backend is the part of your code what you communicate with, e.g. Laravel code, an API, ...

Try adding the following at the beginning of your **catch** part:

```
 if (!error.response) {
    //network error
    console.log('No network connection');
 } else if (error.response) {
   //the rest of your code
```

This should print out **No network connection** in your console.
Run your application, turn off the internet connection and check the console.

These kind of code should always be located in your backend part.

Comment: I ll look it up

Answer (score 1):

My answer maybe different from your question.
When i create a .net core API with Angular i used three things to check is there network or not?

1. subscribe to windows's offline/online event
2. create signalR hub from layout component to API server
3. API request failed (it means lot of incident, but if 1. or 2. case is true i know what cause 3. case

Comment: I used the windows´s offline/online event to change the UI of an android app. Good catch.